# Unable to delete outgoing caller id in twilio api

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to delete a number from the outgoing caller id list. I use the following code:

```
client.outgoing_caller_ids(number.twilio_sid).delete()
```

I get the following error:

```
delete Response: 405 {"code": 20004, "message": "Method not allowed", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20004", "status": 405}
```

I went to the URL for more info but it just says I am not allowed to delete it. Am I missing something painfully obvious?

Comment: Can you show me the link to the docs for `outgoing_caller_ids`?  I can't seem to find it.

Comment: permission issue maybe? can you do it from the console?

Comment: Yeah I can easily do it from twilio.com

Comment: I feel silly, it worked even when I ran it in the Python shell. Turned out there was a bug in my code where I would never commit the number sid to my database and therefore never being able to delete as it was an empty string.